# regarding image downloading function

Tags: image

Can anyone help me to solve my issue regarding the image downloading function? The situation goes like this: actually I wanna download a gantt chart image from a site that generates some string url as the image! not even http://www.example.com/img/image.png but something like http://www.example.com/img/index.php?=task&d=&Work=0...

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding what language or environment you are working in, simply using the full URL with all the GET variables in place will provide you with the image.
It should not matter.

Judging from your comments below, your code is not working because you are using PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function.
Htmlspecialchars will turn symbols that you cannot represent in HTML output simply by adding them to the source of an html document (such as `&`, `<` and `>`) into identifiers that will let the browser know what kind of character to render.

for instance the ampersand (`&`) could be rendered by `&amp;` the HtmlSpecialChars function does this for you.

When your backend code is outputting parts of html source that aren't visible to the user, such as the source of an image in this case, you do not want to use that function.
It will invalidate the URL by replacing all the `&` instances in the url by `&amp;`

Simply do this:

```
<?php print($url); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks friend, but I have already tried using them with PHP and there is no positive response! Basically they are generated to web UI as: 
“$src” = info captured according to “start” and “end” date set by the user on web UI.

Comment: <script type=”text/javascript”>
document.write('<img id="image" alt="Please wait while the Gantt chart is generated... (this might take a minute or two)" src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($src); ?>" />'); //this is the image in Web!

Comment: Var temp = ‘<img id="image" alt="Please wait while the Gantt chart is generated... (this might take a minute or two)" src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($src); ?>" />’;
</script>

Comment: Finally, I capture them using PHP as:
<?php
 $url = ‘<script type=”text/javascript”>temp</script>’; //this generates only the url and works fine!
?>

Comment: With this “url” I used many approaches! Such as: 
- cURL functions! curl_init ($url);
- Even I forced it to download using “header”!
- Jquery!!  (But all failed!!! )

Comment: Sorry, I couldn’t post the code and cannot till Monday, coz I’m not allowed to access from outside!  Suggestions plz..

Comment: Hi tyson, welcome to StackOverflow.
You can edit your question by logging in and clicking 'edit' on your question.
if you add more detail to your question, please do that in the question itself rather than adding comments, it will allow us to help you better :)

Comment: I updated the answer for you, i think this is what was causing you problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and valuable guidance friend. I'm extremely sorry for the delay and inconvenience caused! 

I'm very new "StackOverflow"! And I couldn't reply on time because of my other obligations and duties. On the other hand, regarding the image saving function, we have found a solution and fixed it. Actually, it was done by one of my college!

Once again Thank you very much friend. It was a great support! TC :)